# Numpy binary matrix to chromosome

Tags: python, numpy

I have a binary matrix of shape `N,M`, and I want an *efficient* way to transform it to chromosome, that is, given a row I need a function that returns the indexes of non-zero elements, for example given the row `[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]` the function should return `[0,1,8]`, this could be done with  `np.flatnonzero` for example. I need to apply this transformation to all rows and return a flatten vector representing the binary matrix, for example

`P = np.array([[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]])`

should be transformed to `[018234567]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the non-flat version [`np.nonzero`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html). With a matrix this will give you a tuple with arrays for the rows and columns separately, from which you want the columns:

```
P = np.array([[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]])

rows, col = np.nonzero(P)

print(col)
# [0 1 8 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```py
import numpy as np

P = np.array([[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], [0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0]])

s=''

for i in P:
    for j in np.flatnonzero(i):
        s+=str(j)

print(s)
```